# Get list of description for each type in xml with Python

Tags: python, xml, list, python-xmlschema

I have a xml file with the following format:

```
<batch>
 <type1 type="application/pdf" file="1234.pdf">
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
    <description>Description 1</description>
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
 </type1>
 <type2 type="application/pdf" file="23456.pdf">
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
    <description>Description 1</description>
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
 </type2>
 <type1 type="application/pdf" file="1235.pdf">
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
    <description>Description 2</description>
    <...></...>
    <...></...>
 </type1>
</batch>
```

I want to retrieve a list of type1, type2 within a list of description for that type in the xml. The list result is ['{blabla.com}type1', '{blabla.com/2}type2', '{blabla.com/3}type3', '{blabla.com}type4', etc. ]
I tried:

```
test = ET.parse("...\\index.xml")

type_list = []

for type in test.iter():
    type_list.append(type.tag)

type_list = list(set(type_list))
```

to get all types in xml. But then how can I get all of the description for each type?

The result I want to have:

```
type1: Description 1, Description 2
type2: Description 1, ...
```

Comment: `type.findall('description')` to get description tags inside a `type` node

Comment: The result of type_list is ['{http://www.blabla.com}type1', '{http://www.blabla.com}type2', '{http://www.blabla.com}type3', '{http://www.blabla.com}type4', etc. ]
So, I tried this before it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugly handling of namespace but should work

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
test = ET.parse("test.xml")

type_list = defaultdict(set)
ns="{blabla.com}"
for type_ in test.iter():
    if type_.tag.startswith(ns+'type'):
        ttag=type_.tag.split(ns)[1]
        descrs = type_.findall(ns+'description')
        for descr in descrs:
            type_list[ttag].add(descr.text)

print(type_list)
```

Comment: Why the namespace trick is required? Why not just `list(root)` and iterate over the types?

Comment: @balderman op didn't update his post but he said in the comments there was a namespace

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
xml = '''<batch>
 <type1 type="application/pdf" file="1234.pdf">
    <description>Description 1</description>
   
 </type1>
 <type2 type="application/pdf" file="23456.pdf">
    <description>Description 1</description>
 </type2>
 <type1 type="application/pdf" file="1235.pdf">
    <description>Description 2</description>
 </type1>
</batch>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for _type in list(root):
    data[_type.tag].append(_type.find('description').text)
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'type1': ['Description 1', 'Description 2'], 'type2': ['Description 1']})
```